# How to count cells that are not empty

Tags: excel, count

I have a list of down regulated gene probes for two different clones.

I have used the formula `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F2,$H$2:$H$1670,0)),"",F2)` to give me a list of genes that are down regulated in both clones.

However, I now need to count how many there are and when I try to copy and paste the list to try to remove blank cells I am unable to and they disappear as they are formulas.

I have tried using `COUNTA` to count them but this gives me all of the genes in the left column as technically all middle columns are filled by the formula.

```
G.Ac down               Shared down regulated   Mc.Ac down 
GENE:JGI_V11_619450303  GENE:JGI_V11_619450303  GENE:JGI_V11_3219080103
GENE:JGI_V11_2644330202                         GENE:JGI_V11_534070103
GENE:JGI_V11_1064490203 GENE:JGI_V11_1064490203 GENE:JGI_V11_3146980103
GENE:JGI_V11_3327160202                         GENE:JGI_V11_3018650102
GENE:JGI_V11_3179550203                         GENE:JGI_V11_3018650202
GENE:JGI_V11_3050490103                         GENE:JGI_V11_3146980203
GENE:JGI_V11_1064490103 GENE:JGI_V11_1064490103 GENE:JGI_V11_2378650103
GENE:JGI_V11_1044440103                         GENE:JGI_V11_2378650303
GENE:JGI_V11_3277080303 GENE:JGI_V11_3277080303 GENE:JGI_V11_3146980303
```

How do I either get a copy of all the genes that appear in the middle row OR how do I count the number of genes that appear in the middle row?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(B2:B9,"")`

Comment: Thanks! That gives me the number of cells that do not have a gene name. I know I can simply subtract that from the overall number of cells in the left column, but is there a way I can do it in the first step instead of doing 2 formulas?

Comment: Assuming the blank cells actually have formulas in them: `=COUNTA(B2:B9)-COUNTIF(B2:B9,"")`

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this one of two ways:

- Use one formula to count how many genes appear in the middle column, **or**
- Get a unique list of all genes that appear in the middle column.

I'll show you both solutions, below.

---

#### Use one formula to count the number of populated cells in a column that also has formulas returning "":

You'll want to use the following formula:

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,">*")`

<sup>with `$B$2:$B$10` being your range covering your **Shared down regulated**
 column (sans the header). Change range locations as needed.</sup>

[image: Using COUNTIF]

This formula works by counting all cells in the specified range that have at least one character (done by using the wildcard `*` within the `criteria` part of the function).

**NOTE:** This formula only works on cells that are either formatted as text, or are *not* numbers. Your data set is perfectly acceptable as your data seems to be all strings.

---

#### Return a unique, contiguous list of values from a single column while ignoring blank or ="" cells:

If you'd rather return a unique list of values from your second column, use the following **array** formula in `F2` (this *must* be committed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or it won't work):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:$G1,$B$2:$B$10),0)),"")`

<sup>with `$B$2:$B$10` being your range covering your **Shared down regulated**
 column (sans the header) and `$F$1:$G1` being the new column header you created (mine is called **Genes List**) to hold this unique list (*see image below*). Change range locations as needed.</sup>

<sup>Once you commit the formula in the first cell of the newly created column, you can copy the formula down.</sup>

[image: Creating a unique list]

<sup>With respect to `$F$1:$G1`, you can either:</sup>

 <sup>- put your new column header into `F1` *only* (but still use `$F$1:$G1` in your formula), **or**</sup>

 <sup>- merge cells `F1` and `G1` together.</sup>

The key to making sure your new, unique list excludes both blank cells as well as cells holding `""` (via a formula return) is to ensure the `range` argument of the `COUNTIF` function covers both the header (`F1`) as well as one blank cell (`G1`) of your new column. The blank cell (`G1`) ensures that all blank/empty cells in your data column (column `B`) are accounted for, preventing them from leaving gaps in your new list. Wrapping it all up in `IFERROR` allows you to drag the new range as far down as you want without having to see errors all over the place.